# An Unexpected Error has occured -> after adding custom resource file in APP_GlobalResources

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, resource-files, port, virtual-directory

We have shifted MOSS 2007 solution from one physical server machine to another machine. After hard work, every thing works perfect except one error as below:

> An error occurred during the processing of . The resource object with key 'CSS_Mail' was not found.

After Google I find out that I need to copy that custom resource file from `12\Resources` folder to `virtualdirectories\port\App_GlobalResource`. The Error gone! but after refreshing page, then I get this error:

> An unexpected error has occurred. Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: did you check the ULS logs / Event log for more information about error?

Comment: I could not find any problem, Any idea to do something more?

Comment: how you deploy the solutions? i think retract the solutions and re add and re deploy and put all the file in place before hand

Comment: I have retracted and then re deployed the solution, but it still gives same error: Unexpected error.... totally frustrated what to do ?